# Can we toggle debug logging in android at runtime?

Tags: android

We have a number of components, both native and Android apps running on a device running Android L. 
The problem is the logger resets its logs because of copious logging and it is hard to troubleshoot long running issues.

Each of them will have a DEBUG flag so that they can turn on/off logging

```
if(DEBUG)
  Log.d(...);
```

I was wondering if it is a good idea to be able to toggle this at runtime from a 'dashboard app'.
This dashboard app will use some method to share preferences (persist SystemProperties?).
So each component will upon startup, do a

```
  boolean DEBUG = SystemProperties.get("com.xyz.app1"); // app1, app2, app3...
```

When you need to isolate logging to a few components, then the dashboard app will turn off/on using

```
 SystemProperties.set("com.xyz.app1", false);
```

Can we toggle debug logging in android at runtime?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `adb shell getprop` and `adb shell setprop`.

Comment: you can modify sharedpreferences using Stetho, for example.

Comment: will native applications be able to access it?

Comment: Checking the preference at startup isn't exactly the same as checking it at runtime -- you would need a way to kill all components when the log status changes. If you're going to have a dashboard app, you might as well have that app respond to "how should I log" requests, with the app defaulting to non-debug if nothing talks back. Ideally it would have a way to broadcast state changes back to your apps and services, avoiding the need to kill everything to propagate the change. System properties are not really meant to be used as a substitute for IPC.